# Слишком длинное название?

Tags: youtube

Скажите, пожалуйста, может ли не загрузиться видео на ютьюб из-за слишком длинного названия? Сегодня попробовал загрузить туда двухчасовое видео. А что такое для видео 2 часа? А загрузить не получилось. Единственное, что приходит в голову - это, да, у него очень длинное название.

Comment: Гугл бы дал ответ быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Максимальная длина названия видео - 100 символов (пробелы тоже считаются).
Если у вас неподтвержденный акк на ютуб, нельзя загружать видео длиннее 15 минут.
И если видео весит более 20 Гб, то загрузится только с последней версии браузера

Comment: Ага, понял. Большое спасибо.

Comment: По ходу, дело не в длине названия. Вот видео с длиной названия примерно такой же, как и у того видео, которое я хочу выложить. Сейчас пойду посмотрю, что такое подтвержденный акк.

Comment: Если еще актуально - вот здесь можно подтвердить аккаунт на ютубе: https://www.youtube.com/verify

Comment: VicGayday спасибо. А вот это. Я загрузил видео. Сейчас идет его обработка. Если я сейчас отключу комп, видео опубликуется?